# Tabbar hide badge when Tabbaritem touched

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller, badge

I trying to use tabbar badges but i have  problem ... I have found how to set the badge

but i can't find how to catch the touch event for the tabbaritem so i can delete the badge when the user is on the corresponding tabbaritem

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to implement tabBarController:didSelectViewController: on the tab bar's delegate. To clear the badge, set it to `nil`. For example:

```
- (void) tabBarController:(UITabBarController*)aTabBarController
  didSelectViewController:(UIViewController*)viewController
{
    viewController.tabBarItem.badgeValue = nil;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: Write down inside Viewcontroller of Tabbar on which you have displayed badge.

-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

```
// reseting tabbar badge value...
self.tabBarItem.badgeValue = nil;
```

}